# How can I get the overall stats when using group_by in dplyr?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I am using `dplyr` to calculate some summary statistics across groups, but I would also like to get the same stats for all the data (in the same line of code)

So far I can only think of:

```
aux.1 <- iris %>% 
group_by(Species)  %>% 
summarise("stat1" = mean(Sepal.Length), 
          "stat2" = sum(Petal.Length) )

aux.2 <- iris %>% 
summarise("stat1" = mean(Sepal.Length), 
          "stat2" = sum(Petal.Length) )
```

Anyway I can get all the stats in one line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need two separate `dplyr` chains, but you can put it all together with `bind_rows`:

```
aux <- bind_rows(
  iris %>% 
    group_by(Species)  %>% 
    summarise("stat1" = mean(Sepal.Length), 
              "stat2" = sum(Petal.Length)), 
  iris %>% 
    summarise("stat1" = mean(Sepal.Length), 
              "stat2" = sum(Petal.Length)) %>%
    mutate(Species = "All")
  )

aux
```

> ```
>      Species    stat1 stat2
> 1     setosa 5.006000  73.1
> 2 versicolor 5.936000 213.0
> 3  virginica 6.588000 277.6
> 4        All 5.843333 563.7
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In case you are interested in taking a look at the `data.table` package, this is easy to achieve:

```
library(data.table)
# have to make a copy of the internal data.frame for testing
irisTemp <- iris
setDT(irisTemp)

# calculate group statistics
irisTemp[, c("meanVal", "sumVal") := .(mean(Sepal.Length), sum(Petal.Length)),
         by="Species"]
```

This can be a quick and efficient library for large data sets.